# Movie review crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want to crawl all these movie reviews in this page.
[Which part in red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2ugm.jpg)

I tried to crawl with this code. (I used Jupiter Notebook-Anaconda3)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_url = "https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=174903&type=after&page=1"
resp = requests.get(test_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
soup
```

---

```
score_result = soup.find('div', {'class': 'score_result'})
lis = score_result.findAll('li')
lis[:3]
```

---

```
from urllib.request import urljoin  #When I ran this block and next block it didn't save any reviews.
review_text=[]
#review_text = lis[0].find('p').getText()
list_soup =soup.find_all('li', 'p')

for item in list_soup:
review_text.append(item.find('p').get_text())
```

---

```
review_text[:5] #Nothing was saved.
```

As I wrote in third block and forth block nothing was saved. What is the problem?

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add content. `BeautifulSoup`, `urllib` and `request` doesn't run JavaScript. You would need `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you would have to find url used by JavaScript to get data and use this url in your code.

Comment: list_soup is empty as ```soup.find_all(...)``` returns and empty list

Comment: maybe you should use `find_all('li')` instead of `find_all('li', 'p')`

Comment: just as side note, ```find_all('li', 'p')``` is really looking for ```<li class = "p"></li>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get what you want. Tested in python within Jupyter Notebook (latest)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import NavigableString

test_url = "https://movie.naver.com/movie/bi/mi/pointWriteFormList.nhn?code=174903&type=after&page=1"
resp = requests.get(test_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html.parser')
movie_lst = soup.select_one('div.score_result')
ul_movie_lst = movie_lst.ul
for movie in ul_movie_lst:
    if isinstance(movie, NavigableString):
        continue

    score = movie.select_one('div.star_score em').text
    name = movie.select_one('div.score_reple p span').text
    review = movie.select_one('div.score_reple dl dt em a span').text

    print(score + "\t" + name)
    print("\t" + review)
```

**Preview**
[image: Code Preview]